# AS3 Firing projectiles on an angle

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm not sure what to do with regard to this matter, and I was hoping some of you could help.

So I have 3 arrays of projectiles, one that shoots positive on the Y-axis, one that's negative on the X-axis and one that shoots positive on the X-axis (basically, shooting in a T formation) and what I would like is to have two more sets of projectiles fire between those, so there would be 5 of them firing in the following directions: W SW S SE E

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could achieve this?

Comment: Nothing thus far, I'm a bit stumped as to how to go about it and I've been brainstorming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your projectiles are traveling at some velocity along the x and y axis, all you need to do is set the x and y velocity with the according cos/sin of the angle you want the projectile to travel at. Then you multiply by your speed at which you want them to travel.

Assuming you have your `velocity` variable

```
velocity.x = Math.cos( angleInRadians ) * speed;
velocity.y = Math.sin( angleInRadians ) * speed;
```

Then your projectile just increments across the axis in accordance to your new velocity:

```
projectile.x += velocity.x;
projectile.y += velocity.y;
```

For your specific implementation, your angles are going to be at increments of 45 degrees. So your `angleInRadians` would be `45 * Math.PI / 180`

Comment: I've never used anything like `velocity.x`, how exactly would I implement that?

Comment: Usually most people create their velocity variable as a `Point` in AS3. Then that really is about it, everything else is pretty straight forward, you move your object's x & y according to the velocity x and y. The only difference is when you want the object to move at an angle as posted in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I can definitely see how this would be implemented, I've just never used velocity as a `Point` before. I'm currently a student working on this project on the side of schooling. Sometimes class work just doesn't cover everything.

Comment: Best way to learn is on your own anyway :) You're in the right place